# Django query using filter, groupby, count()

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

How to perform django query for below mysql query:

```
This is Django model
class Passengers(models.Model):       
    id = models.CharField(max_length=128)        
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    orgId = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=128)

MYSQL
------
SELECT `ref` , count( 'id' )
FROM `dispatcher_passengers`
WHERE `orgId_id` =1
GROUP BY `ref`
```

i have a model with id,ref columns.

i want to get the count(id) with 'ref'.

so  how can i write above query in django query sets format.

Comment: Please show your Django models, otherwise we have to guess what they are called.

Comment: give the doc a chance https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

what about this way:

```
refs = Passengers.objects.values('ref')
refs = set(refs)
ref_count = lambda ref: Passengers.objects.filter(ref = ref).count
counts = [ (ref, ref_count(ref)) for ref in refs ]
```

update:

```
from django.db.models import Count
count = Passengers.objects.values('ref').annotate(Count('id')).order_by()
```